# nesting <choice> and <sequence> to create arbitrary element selection in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype, xmlschema

I would like to validate my XML using an XSD. The XML is supposed to contain complex elements with some (none to all) elements of a given set. I think the straight foward solution for the complex element is

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> 
  <xs:element name="bar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> 
  <xs:element name="bee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> 
</xs:sequence>
```

I want to get rid of the set order of elements, plus I want to get rid of the `minOccurs="0"` in every line, so that

```
<foo>text</foo>
<bee>text</bee> 
<bar>text</bar>
```

is also valid. My idea was to write

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
      <xs:element1>
      <xs:element2> 
      ... 
   </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
```

which should translate to "select one element of the list as many times as you want to."

But it does not allow me to put an appearance restriction (like `maxOccurs=1`) on individual elements.
Is there a better way to validate an XML without forcing a given order of elements?

Comment: Which version of XSD do you use? Have you looked at `xs:all`? Also, it would help if you explain in more detail which instances samples you want to consider valid and which ones invalid.

Comment: `xs:all´ does not support elements with maxOccurs>1 as far as I understood it. But yes it is also a possibility.

Comment: I use no specific XSD version but XML 1.0 (first line: <?xml version = 1.0?>). I am quite new to this, so there might be room for improvement...

Comment: XSD 1.1 "allows arbitrary values of minOccurs and maxOccurs on the particles of a model group using the compositor xs:all", thus, newer versions of Xerces or Saxon support that, as does Altova.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that further :)